# Hide UISearchbar after returning from another View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I found a lot about hiding UISearchBar and what seems to work for most people is:

`[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,44) animated:YES];`

If I put this in my ViewDidLoad method my SearchBar is hidden behind the NavigationBar - good.

BUT: If I switch Views and then come back to my TableView with the SearchBar at the top this is always getting displayed.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in avance!

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,44) animated:YES];` in `viewWillApper` (instead of `viewDidLoad` )Method, your problem will solved.

Comment: Thx for the answer - I forgot to mention in my post that I also tried putting the line in the viewWillAppeare method but that does'nt change the behaviour. On first launch the SearchBar is hidden as expected but if I switch the view and come back to the TableView the SearchBar is not hidden anymore.

Comment: just write  in viewWillAppear method.. [self.yourSearchBarObject setHidden:YES];

Comment: OK - my bad. This does indeed fix it.I ried it with a new project and it works fine. So for some reason something in my other project is messed up.